# Unable to read json using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

In the below code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Dashboard</title>
        <!-- Libs -->
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script>
        var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', []);
        countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
            $http.get('country_codes.json').success(function(data) {
                $scope.countries = data;
            });
        });
        </script>   
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="CountryCtrl">

    </body>
</html>
```

---

/* country_codes.json */

```
[
  {
    "code": "AD",
    "name": "Andorra",
    "population": "84000"
  },
  {
    "code": "AE",
    "name": "United Arab Emirates",
    "population": "4975593"
  }
]
```

---

As per debugging, I do not see any error and the callback functions does not execute.

Why the controller callback does not execute?

Comment: You should handle the `.error` callback too, not just the `.success`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add error function, and you will see error details:

```
<script>
        var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', []);
        countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
              $http.get('country_codes.json')
    .then(function(data) {$scope.countries = data;}
,
          function(data) {console.log("error: "+data)});
 });
 </script>
```

change the json to:

```
{
    "countries": [
     {
    "code": "AD",
    "name": "Andorra",
    "population": "84000"
  },
     {
    "code": "AE",
    "name": "United Arab Emirates",
    "population": "4975593"
  }

    ]  

}
```

Answer (score 2):

After adding ng-app="countryApp" in your html tag its works for me.

Comment: Yes, ng-app tells angularjs that HTML tag element is the "owner" of an AngularJS application. You can add ng-app to any tag like a div tag

Comment: But still the code does not work. Can you fiddle the code?